# Pandas Python - How to group customer IDs, examine if a column contains a text, and have corresponding outputs in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My dataframe has 2 columns: i) Customer ID ii) Status. For each customer, if there is any rows pertaining to that customer that contains the status 'Confirmed', it should return 'Active' in a third column, else it should return 'Inactive'. Appreciate any help please, thanks!

```
**Current Dataframe**

Customer ID    Status         
A              Confirmed      
A              Transferred    
A              Confirmed       
A              Withdrawn       
B              Transferred     
B              Withdrawn       
B              Transferred     
C              Confirmed      
D              Withdrawn   

---

**Expected Output**

Customer ID    Status          Customer Status
A              Confirmed       Active
A              Transferred     Active 
A              Confirmed       Active
A              Withdrawn       Active
B              Transferred     Inactive
B              Withdrawn       Inactive
B              Transferred     Inactive
C              Confirmed       Active
D              Withdrawn       Inactive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if match at least one values per groups by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html), because need mask with same size like original column use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), last pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = df['Status'].eq('Confirmed').groupby(df['Customer ID']).transform('any')
df['Customer Status'] = np.where(m, 'Active','Inactive')

print (df)
  Customer ID       Status Customer Status
0           A    Confirmed          Active
1           A  Transferred          Active
2           A    Confirmed          Active
3           A    Withdrawn          Active
4           B  Transferred        Inactive
5           B    Withdrawn        Inactive
6           B  Transferred        Inactive
7           C    Confirmed          Active
8           D    Withdrawn        Inactive
```

Or get all `Customer ID` if match at least one value and compare original columns by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
m = df['Customer ID'].isin(df.loc[df['Status'].eq('Confirmed'),'Customer ID'])
df['Customer Status'] = np.where(m, 'Active','Inactive')
```